# Moment returning previous day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date:

```
EventDate: "2018-10-10T00:00:00Z"
```

I run it through `moment`:

```
let date = moment(event.EventDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

And I get the previous day:

```
date:  10/09/2018
```

What is happening?

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate; there is a specific answer on `moment` that fixes the time zone issue.

Comment: Your date is the previous day in your time zone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) While this talks about the native Date object, that's what moment uses anyway.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, it is the same issue with time zones as your link.  The answer is at 2 votes and near the bottom of the page.  This one I feel gives a more succinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `utc()` to respect universal time, as your time format is already in utc.

```js
var EventDate= "2018-10-10T00:00:00Z"
let date = moment(EventDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```